# Symfony2 routing using submit button

Tags: symfony

I am trying to route from one page (Admin page) to another (ListQuestions) using Symfony2 docs, still i am unable to do it using submit button...

Admin Controller :

```php
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Admin();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->getMethod()== 'POST')
    {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->'PRIPRIBundle:ListQuestions:index.html.twig');
        }
        }
            return $this->redirect('PRIPRIBundle:Admin:index.html.twig'.
             array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
    }
```

routing.yml :

```
_index:
    pattern:  index
    defaults: { _controller: PRIPRIBundle:Admin:index }
```

index.html.twig :

```
    name="input" action="" method="post">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? There's a syntax error on this line: `return $this->redirect($this->'PRIPRIBundle:ListQuestions:index.html.twig');
`

Comment: I corrected this error but still i am not able to run the code :

Attempted to call method "bindRequest" on class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form" in C:\wamp\www\PRI\src\PRI\PRIBundle\Controller\AdminController.php line 70

Comment: Try $form->handleRequest($request)

Answer (score 1):

What is the documentation you are following ? There are a bunch of errors here.

- How can you redirect to a template file ?
- bindRequest method has been deprecated for at least one full year.
- What is this createCreateForm method ?
- Your routing does not match your action PRIPRIBundle:Admin:index -> newAction.

I think you should take a closer look to the latest documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html (v2.7 right now).

Comment: I followed this document also, but I am inable to navigate from one page to another page :(

This example assumes that you submit the form in a "POST" request and to the same URL that it was displayed in. 

Its mentioned that we  will learn later how to change the request method and the target URL of the form, and i am facing problem in navigating to the next target URL.